# Simplifying repeated usage of typings pattern

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings

I have these 2 interfaces:

```
export interface Converter<T> {
  decode?: Decoder<T>;
  encode?: Encoder<T>;
  notify?: Notifier<T>;
  type?: T;
}

export interface Api {
  state: Converter<State>;
  water: Converter<Water>;
  version: Converter<Versions>;
}
```

And in many function I want to either make sure a return value is the generic based on a parameter that is passed on to the function, like so

```
get<Name extends keyof Api, Value = Api[Name]["type"]>(
  name: Name
): Value {
  // ...
}
```

which means if I call `get("state")` the return value will be of the type `State` and if I call `get("water")` the return value will be of the type `Water`

I also use that when I have multiple parameters:

```
set<Name extends keyof Api, Value = Api[Name]["type"]>(
  name: Name,
  value: Value
): void {
  // ...
}
```

The type of `value` depends on the `name`. But I have to write the same pattern:

```
<Name extends keyof Api, Value = Api[Name]["type"]>
```

again and again. Can I define these types *once* and reuse them in TypeScript?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't define them once because they depend very much on the type parameter in the function, but some of the boilerplate around it can be cleaned up with a few aliases.

```
type ApiKey = keyof Api;
type ApiValue<Name extends ApiKey> = Api[Name]["type"];
```

We can't get around the `Name` type parameter but the `Value` one isn't necessary when only expected to be the default, and used once.

```
class X {
    get<Name extends ApiKey>(name: Name): ApiValue<Name> {
      return ...;
    }
}
```

Then the usage:

```
new X().get('state') // State
new X().get('unknown') // Argument of type '"unknown"' is not assignable to parameter 
                       // of type '"state" | "water" | "version"'.
```

Comment: That seems to be exactly what I was looking for, thank you!